Issues running VirtualBox after installing on Linux debian (bookworm)
When trying to load VirtualBox I receive this error message:
daddy@penguin:~$ virtualbox
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1725 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (6.6.65-06269-g48dafd014a7a) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Qt WARNING: QObject::connect(UITranslationEventListener, QIRichTextLabel): invalid nullptr parameter
Qt WARNING: QObject::connect(UITranslationEventListener, QIArrowButtonPress): invalid nullptr parameter
Qt WARNING: QObject::connect(UITranslationEventListener, QIArrowButtonPress): invalid nullptr parameter
Qt WARNING: QObject::connect(UITranslationEventListener, QIArrowSplitter): invalid nullptr parameter
Qt WARNING: QObject::connect(UITranslationEventListener, QIDialogButtonBox): invalid nullptr parameter
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

how do I fix it so I can use VB?

What did you research, what you try?

6.6.65-06269-g48dafd014a7a — is that a kernel you built yourself? Does it support modules? A missing /proc/modules suggests it doesn’t.

it was a link I follow online. i'll see if I can find it again.

I followed these steps  https://fasttrack.debian.net/

and this one   https://linuxiac.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-debian-12-bookworm/

You must be smart, you need to figure it out dude. Use your head. It's a custom kernel module and every single device you get will be attached as well. You're not the only one, i'm in the same boat. Check /dev/.lxc, May help you out a little bit to know what you're working with.

Thank you for the tip and compliment. I am reasonably smart but not as smart as it may seem. The kernel isn't a custom build. Its what came stock in my Chromebook. I am just now learning about coding and running scripts and commands. As of now at least I have a very small idea of what I'm doing. I am smart and learn fast tho. An answer to this will be found. Again, thank you.

Trust me, it's custom. I've been working on this for 3 years.  Debian bookwork has a huge issue. I was able to get master finally. 6 threat actors, got the Photos and addresses of all 6 just recently. Debian has a huuge bug in it.  Does your machine by any chance come up as (unknown).  Check your resolv.conf as well, how are the settings? I recently got a new laptop and this bug is messed up, completely bugged my new laptop. I found data going all the way back to 1969, japanese industrial standard terminals, December 31, 1969 to 1978 where BASIC, FORTRAN and COBOL coding is used. Also did you check the /dev? ls -la  , is .lxc there by default without installing anything? If so cd into it and you will see over 100,000 consoles. Try run picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0  You are literally the only other person i have come across that is stuck with that issue and i am seeing just 1 other person connected to me.
Just saying, not saying you are but it is quite odd.
You can also use minicom instead of picocom. ip a should show you're on a bridged connection.  Most virus scans wont detect any issues, checkout lynis, rkhunter.  You also may have anonymous authentication set up with perl, check your man pages in /usr/share/man also unscrew the back of your laptop and unplug the xhci controller for bluetooth, your bluetooth will still work it will just prevent any threat actors from connecting to via bluetooth while trying to figure out this issue. Install nmap go into /usr/share/nmap/scripts and run some scans on yourself and make sure ufw is disabled. If you can send messages on here id like you to send me over an email where i can contact you.

my machine does act strangely. Like it don't want to recognize my external hard drive. the drive is brand new. I just bought it last week. formatted to NTSF and have used on this machine. now it don't hardly recognize it at all. even lsusb finds it no problem. I am very new to all this Linux and coding stuff so I didn't know debian was a train wreck. I have noticed more and more errors occuring lately but i'm very careful about entering any commands or scripts. I don't just type in anything I find floating around out there. maybe I need to switch to something different.

Mine as well, Don't dwell on that to much just know that me and you have a very important job to do. You can do a simple check just to confirm what i am saying, clone the repository hound and then cd into it, bash hound.sh , that link that shows up. Put it into your search bar and you dont even need to confirm your location but its good to do so, so you know 100%, You're going to see 1-2 Google administrators connected to you and your IP which is not going to show your exact location, actually probably not even close. Your locations are hidden for security purposes. You need to install lxd/lxc, do lxd init and what not, launch an ubuntu container either 20.04 or 22.04. You can also install openvpn and setup. It's going to show a peer to peer , connect the containers from lxd to eth0 as its already bridged and looping to google data centers. You can also install the app wifi analyzer, you will see its not directly connected and its bridging off as if its cloned. Security purposes. You set that all up and get back to me here please, there is also a reason everything you open appears in the browsers as google is facing massive breaches at the moment from north korea. Goodluck, dont bother messing with that resolv.conf, everything will still work fine. We want the data uncorrupted and attaching to the right individuals who own there lost data.
